# What do the numbers in the yellow diamonds mean?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

In a battle, I noticed that everyone has a yellow diamond with a number in it, both my party members and the monsters we are fighting. What do those mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This yellow diamonds represents the player/monster's turn order. You may test that. Create a combat and check the numbers: the (1) goes for the first one to attack and then goes.

I've been lurking on the internet looking for Knights of Pen and Paper threads/posts/etc and I found your thread. I'm one of Behold Studio devs.  You may contact us at contato@beholdstudios.com.br if you'd like.

Comment: Very cool - now that I was paying attention, it totally makes sense. :D

Comment: It helps a lot for you to make some certain strategy in the battle and maybe helps you choose to attack or heal a group member on that turn or maybe focus the monster that will attack before your healer, who knows? (: